# form not working in jquery hovercard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, hover, mouseover

I am using [jquery hovercard plugin](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard). I created a hiddendiv which contains a form. So it returns the form on hovering.

Later I noticed that the form's submit,reset,clear options were not working. Let me know where I'm doing wrong. I think this plugin doesn't handle the `<form>`. I might be wrong.

Below is what I've tried.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40036711/jquery.hovercard.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$('#demo-basic').hovercard({detailsHTML:$('#hiddenDiv').html(),
width: 210
});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    font-family:Sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:15px;
    line-height:1.5em;
}
#hiddenDiv
{
    display:none;
}
strong
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
</head>
--------------
--------------
<body>
<p><label id="demo-basic">Filter</label></p>
<div id="hiddenDiv">
<form name='testform' action='$action'>
some <input> and <option> tags...
<a href='javascript:document.testform.reset()'><img src='$path/resetimage.png'></a>
<a href='javascript:document.testform.clear()'><img src='$path/clearimage.png'></a>
<a href='javascript:document.testform.submit()'><img src='$path/submitimage.png'></a>
</form>
-----
-----
```

Comment: try something like this javascript:document.getElementsByName('testform').reset()

Comment: do you get any console errors?

Comment: @Rajesh: I think it skips the `<form>` and the output which I get is due to only `<input>` tag. So if the `<form>` is not working fine then `submit`, `reset`, 'clear` will fail eventually.

Comment: @Batman: Yes, `Cannot call method 'submit' of undefined` and some more, I think all these are related to `form`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, it's not due to the plugin, the reason of the error was that I tried to use `<form>` inside another `<form>` which was stupid. Actually the html file was too big that I didn't come to know that.